# Command Line: manipulating file names; grep?

Tags: command-line, grep, renaming

I currently have a directory of files with date based names in the format `mmddyy`:

```
    nxd060815a.html
    nxd060915a.html
    nxd061015a.html
```

and would like to change file name format to `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
    nxd2015-06-08a.html
    nxd2015-06-09a.html
    nxd2015-06-10a.html
```

How would I do this from the command line?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls | awk '{ system("mv " $0 " " substr($0,1,3) "20" substr($0,8,2) "-" substr($0,4,2) "-" substr($0,6,2) substr($0,10,6))}'
```

run the above from the dir the files are in.  You should be able to figure out whats going on, so no other comment.